# PC to PC communication using Java

Tags: java, instant-messaging

Is there such thing to communicate with 1 pc to another pc using JAVA. Concept is the same as Window Live Messenger but just want to know if there is such thing. If there is, can give some example


Regards

Comment: Do you mean an application written in Java that does this? Or a way to accomplish similar functionality using the Java programming language?

Comment: a way To accomplish similar functionality using the Java programming language

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the Smack API which uses Jabber: http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/

Gettting Started Guide:
 http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/gettingstarted.html

Tutorial:
http://pauldeng.blogspot.com/2009/09/smack-api-tutorial.html

Comment: this is such a great information. thanks. now I want to find out how to use this smack api together with jabber

Answer (score 1):

You can try socket communication, have a look at java.net package, where you can treat one pc as server Socket and another as client Socket.

Answer (score 0):

At the lowest level you are going to have to use TCP or UDP for the message exchange as Java doesn't support any other protocols (yet).

You may want to have a look at the [JGroups](http://www.jgroups.org/) project, it is mature library that can help you create networked applications. It's [basic tutorial](http://www.jgroups.org/tutorial/html/ch02.html) actually shows how to implement a [simple chat application](http://www.jgroups.org/tutorial/html/ch02.html#d0e281).

Answer (score -1):

Regardless of the language you would probably use some standard protocol like TDC/IP or UDP to exchange data between instances of the application. And yes, Java certainly supports those.